# Bitmap loading in device

Tags: android, lazy-loading

In my application I'm using **Lazy loading** technique.I referred [this tutorial](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/LazyAdapter.java) . In emulator(android 2.1) image is loading,but in device(android 2.3.4) image is not loading.Only android icon is loading.

my getview code:

```
if (convertView   == null) {
    //this should only ever run if you do not get a view back            
    LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelistrow, null); 

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    convertView.setTag(holder);         
} else { 
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();         
}
//       
imageLoader.DisplayImage(kickerimage[position], image);

// holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//////       items=itemsarray[position];
         holder.text.setText(itemsarray[position]);
```

I am totally confused why this is happening in device.Help to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.  Try this .

```
public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
  {

    View localView = ((LayoutInflater)this.topcouponpage.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(2130903044, null);
    String str = localOfferCategories.getImagelink();
    if (!str.trim().startsWith("http://"))
      str = "http://" + str;
    ImageView localImageView = (ImageView)localView.findViewById(2131099676);
    this.imgloader.DisplayImage(str, localImageView);

    return localView;
  }
}
```

Also give this permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pramod J George..<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> This did the trick..Its solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Test your internet connection before loading images :

```
if (getConnectionState() == false)
    // ErrorHandling("No Internet Connection Found!! Please Try Later on with Internet Connection!");
else
    // perform further execution
```

Declare this function :

```
//To check the internet connection
    private boolean getConnectionState() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        Log.v("NetworkInfo","NetworkInfo = "+ni);
        if (ni == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Make sure with this permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Pratik Sharma..If there is no INTERNET permission means how the text content is displaying??

Comment: @Subburaj your app is running in emulator and not in device so it might indicate internet connection issue.

Comment: Pratik Sharma..I am displaying image and a text content(which is also fetched from url) in a row in listview.If that text is coming displaying means there is issue with Internet i think so..